# How can I get Mathematica to recognize that $ab^* + ba^* = 2\Re(ab^*)$?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

Mathematica understands that $z + z^* = 2\Re(z)$,

```
FullSimply[z + Conjugate[z]]
(* output: 2 Re[z] *)
```

However, Mathematica does not simplify the expression

```
Conjugate[a] b + Conjugate[b] a
```

Is there a way that I can get Mathematica to recognize these sorts of combinations?

Note that

```
ComplexExpand[Conjugate[a] b + Conjugate[b] a, {a,b}]
```

produces

```
2 Im[a] Im[b] + 2 Re[a] Re[b]
```

but I would prefer to simply have it in the more compact form `2 Re[Conjugate[a]b]`

Edit:

Here's an example of something I'd like to simplify:

```
v = {a, b, c};
m = {{1, 1, 1 + I}, {1, 1, 1}, {1 - I, 1, 1}};
Expand[Conjugate[v].m.v]
```

Essentially an expansion of the form $\vec{v}^\dagger H \,\vec{v}$ where $H$ is a Hermitian matrix. The expression is manifestly real, and there will always be terms which combine to either the real or imaginary parts of terms like $a^*b$. I'd like to find all the pairs and combine them into either $\Re(a^*b)$ or $\Im(a^*b)$.

Comment: Have you tried [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand)?

Comment: @CarlWoll I updated it, unfortunately, `ComplexExpand` produces twice as many terms as I would like in an already very cluttered expression

Comment: `Conjugate[a] b + Conjugate[b] a /. Conjugate[a_] b_ + Conjugate[b_] a_ -> 2 Re[a Conjugate[b]]`?

Comment: I don't understand... when I try: ComplexExpand[Conjugate[a] b + Conjugate[b] a], I get 2 a b as an answer, which makes sense because ComplexExpand effecitively assumes a and b are real-valued.

Comment: @bills Try `ComplexExpand[Conjugate[a] b + Conjugate[b] a, {a, b}]`, with `a`, `b` specified to be complex.

Comment: sorry my mistake I typed it instead of copying, I did specify them to be complex

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform that might work, but I have a very complicated expression with many terms of the for `Conjugate[a_]b`, if I could figure out how to get Mathematica to group these terms into pairs properly then I could do that

Comment: @Kai It'd be easier for everyone if you could include a MWE where my replacement above does not work.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I've added an example

Comment: Astonishingly, I tried this: `Simplify[ComplexExpand[
  Conjugate[a]*b + Conjugate[b]*a], {a, b} \[Element] Complexes, 
 ComplexityFunction :> (LeafCount[#] &)]` and Mma terurned an erroneous answer: `2 a b`. I have Mma 12 on Win7. This looks like a bug for me.